# Why can't moderator's tag edits be done without "bumping" the question

Tags: discussion

Recently a moderator (with an 82K rep) went through and edited about 30 old question, deleting tags which he apparently judged to be inappropriately used.  While I suppose this is a commendable "cleanup" activity, it "bumps" all of those questions to the front of the "Top Questions" list, obscuring most "real" activity on the board.

Isn't there some way to perform such updates without messing things up for everyone else?

Comment: Does  reviving some old questions  from time to time really impair ordinary activity?

Comment: @Josh61 - It means that when you look at the "Top Questions" list there's nothing there.  Though, I suppose if by "ordinary activity" you mean doing stuff other than waste time on SE, maybe it actually helps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I edit my very-old-questions without pushing it onto the "active" feed?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/7952/how-do-i-edit-my-very-old-questions-without-pushing-it-onto-the-active-feed)

Answer (score 7):

There is, but not in this case. You saw only the fixes that I was unable to do *en masse*.

Mostly this was for the [verbal](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verbal) tag. This was being variously used for [gre](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gre), [speech](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/speech), [deverbal-nouns](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deverbal-nouns), [verb-phrases](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verb-phrases), and other sundry things. It was therefore not possible to merge it into any other one tag, as there were too many mappings.

It is, as you see, quite a bad tag, so I got rid of it. It could always return, but probably should not.

Answer (score 6):

[Stack Exchange does not support it.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131508/chaos-like-option-for-moderators-to-edit-without-bumping) It's important for all revisions, even ones made by moderators, to be reviewed by other users.

There are a few existing options for people who aren't interested in reviewing tag edits:

- to see the most recently asked questions, they can view the [newest questions list](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest).
- to see recent answers, they can [search using "is:answer"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235102/finding-questions-with-the-newest-answers-anywhere-on-site) and then sort the results by "newest." (Here's a link to the [newest answers on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aanswer).)

As tchrist said, moderators do have special options for dealing with tags as a whole (deleting or merging a particular tag) but not for making edits to the tags on individual questions.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think it's that bad a thing. If the tagging of the question is changed it may put it into view for people who have a specific interest in a certain field - and thus tag.

Since the favorite tags color the questions differently it is a good thing that after a change in the associated tags the question is bumped to the front page.