# Why are all the questions about money?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

At the moment, the top 10 questions on [EL&U](http://English.stackexchange.com) are almost all about [money](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/money) and its linguistics.

[image: Top questions]
[image: Top questions]

Is there a problem with the prioritisation algorithm, is the tag is being purposefully advertised, or is this all a massive coincidence?

**Related:** [mods bumping up old questions](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9376/184766)

Comment: Tags are being edited on a number of questions having to do with currency. That is all. No sinister plot. Move along. Nothing to see here.

Comment: Phew, I was worried for a moment there. It's good to see that the site does get some TLC once in a while.

Comment: That was me, I did the money part of the currency re-tagging.

Comment: I'll do smaller batches next time ;)

Comment: @Helmar, yes, I've just noticed your [call to action](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/9468/184766). Perhaps smaller batches could work, but honestly, it's not too bad.  Keep up the good work!

Comment: @Helmar I prefer one large disruption (at a relatively quiet time on the site) to multiple disruptions spread out over several days.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey can you accept Andrew's answer to keep this from bumping up if you agree that your concern has been addressed properly?

Comment: @Helmar, certainly, my apologies

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not the top questions, it's active questions.

Tag edits bump questions. See [Call to action: Let's tidy up the currency tag](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9468/call-to-action-lets-tidy-up-the-currency-tag)